# Alternative representations of a polynomial

Tags: polynomials

Suppose we have the polynomial $z^4-2 z^3-12 z^2+13 z+11$. $\;$Is there a way to manipulate it into $(z^2-z)^2-13 (z^2-z)+11$ ? How should I tackle this problem ?

Comment: Could you rephrase the question? The second polynomial is different from the first (not only different in terms of form, but _completely_ different).

Comment: @Jinxed, No they are exactly the same polynomials, with different forms, `z^4-2 z^3-12 z^2+13 z+11=(z^2-z)^2-13 (z^2-z)+11`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See[`PolynomialReduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PolynomialReduce.html).

```
reduce[poly_, form_, x_] := 
  With[{ord = Exponent[poly, x] - Exponent[form, x]},
   Flatten[
     PolynomialReduce[poly, form^Range[ord, 1, -1], x]
     ].form^Range[ord, 0, -1]];

reduce[z^4 - 2 z^3 - 12 z^2 + 13 z + 11, z^2 - z, z]
(*
  11 - 13 (-z + z^2) + (-z + z^2)^2
*)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Function[{poly, sub, var},
  Module[{k},
   # - #2 & @@ Eliminate[{poly == 0, k == sub}, var] /. k -> sub
   ]
  ][z^4 - 2 z^3 - 12 z^2 + 13 z + 11, z^2 - z, z]
```

> ```
>  11 - 13 (-z + z^2) + (-z + z^2)^2
> ```

Answer (score 1):

A nice one-liner:

```
Fold[#1 /. z -> #2 &, Decompose[z^4 - 2 z^3 - 12 z^2 + 13 z + 11, z]]
   11 - 13 (-z + z^2) + (-z + z^2)^2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SolveAlways[11 + 13 z - 12 z^2 - 2 z^3 + z^4 == c + b (-z + z^2) + a (-z + z^2)^2, z]
```

{{a -> 1, b -> -13, c -> 11}}

Comment: And we get this prior knowledge .. how ?